# MongoDB Matches query building

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson, mongo-collection

my users collections will have data like this

```
{ name:"steve" }, { name:"david" }, { name:"sana" }, { name:"robert" }
```

My query is like this

```
 var myCollections= _database.GetCollection<RawBsonArray>("users");
 var query = Query.Matches("name", "Steve Sam Steward Savior Sana");
 myCollections.Find(query);
```

Above query will find all user names that matches *"Steve Sam Steward Savior Sana"*. **But I want any user name matches with any word in *"Steve Sam Steward Savior Sana"***

How can I make the above query work in reverse

Expected result is  `{ name:"steve" },{ name:"sana" }`

I went doing `ForEach` loop, but I am not sure if that is the right way.

**This is what I am trying to achieve**

```
_users.Any(x => "Steve Sam Steward Savior Sana".ToLower().Contains(x.name.ToLower()));
```

Comment: Shouldnt you be doing an in clause?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator.  Although, I'm not familiar with C#, this is how it can be done in the shell:

```js
db.users.find({"name":{$in:["Steve", "Sam", "Steward", "Savior", "Sana"]}})
```

I hope this will help you come up with the equivalent in C#.

Comment: I don't think it's do-able in MongoDB.  Can you not using a String method to split/tokenize the string in your client program?  I just googled and found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Comment: here is what I am trying to achieve  _users.Any(x => "Steve Sam Steward Savior Sana".ToLower().Contains(x.name.ToLower()));

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var usernames = new List<string>() {@"Steve", @"Sam", @"Steward", @"Savior", @"Sana"};
// regex token list
var tokens = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < usernames.Count; i++)
{
    // create the regex format
    var userRegex = string.Format("^{0}", usernames[i]);
    tokens.Add(userRegex);
}
var searchByUsernameRegex = string.Join(@"|", tokens);
Collection.Find(Query.Matches("Username", new BsonRegularExpression(searchByUsernameRegex))).ToList();
```

**OR**

```
// regex token list
var tokens = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
{
    // create the regex format
    var userRegex = string.Format("^{0}", users[i]);
    tokens.Add(userRegex);
}
// create regex to match the usernames
var regexes = tokens.Select(x => new Regex(x)).ToList();
// construct the query
var usersQuery = Query.In("Username", new BsonArray(regexes));
```

Comment: "Steve Sam Steward Savior Sana" this is a dynamic string which can have alpha numeric values. in order to follow your way, I will have to split the string by space and do regex match

Comment: yes it is not a problem to call "name1 name2".Split(' ') to tokenize the search query

Comment: Sorry. bad idea to use regular expression for wildcard search while dealing with 1000's of records

Comment: When using starts with(^) on indexed Username field it will not be a problem. I've implemented this solution and run it against 10M of user test data. It works like a charm.